# Mixing aws and app engine

Tags: google-app-engine, amazon-web-services, cloud

We are starting a new project that requires two main components:

1. Backend for task management, e.g retrieve a task from a queue and according to some specific logic validate it.
2. Run a real compiler on that specific task and create an executable that an end user should receive.

We love app engine, however the second part will require a concrete instance where an actual compiler will have to be installed, app engine is not capable here. We were thinking to mix both app engine and aws instances to accomplish the task (part 1 will be app engine and part 2 will be aws).

All of our senses say it's a bad idea:

- unneeded traffic between the two providers, someone needs to pay for that unfortunately.
- We'll have to deal with two systems, two deployments process, each system has its own quirks --> double the work.

But we love app engine.

Does anyone has any experience in combining the two systems? any recommendations ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no reason why what you suggest won't work, especially if you separate your concerns well, by exposing a clean 'compiler' interface on AWS or a similar service. Yes, you will have to pay for traffic between the two services, but this is unlikely to be substantial. If you are serving up the end result to the user, you can link them directly to AWS, rather than fetching it with your app first.

Comment: Thanks. I also want to add these responses - http://groups.google.com/group/google-appengine/browse_thread/thread/b7c0c108f58fe209/82f944753e0b5099?lnk=gst&q=efi+merdler#82f944753e0b5099

Answer (score 0):

AWS's EC2s are literally just vanilla linux boxes in the sky. I would also throw out the suggestion of just moving to it completely. Porting your system over may be easier than it sounds if you're unix savvy.